# centos 5.x basic firewall settings on the commandline

Tags: linux, centos, firewall

I'm using a dedicated host. Unfortunately, when I use x windows with xming, it tends to freeze up the x windows session. This is keeping me from calling system-config-securitylevel and making changes to the firewall. Is there a way to do it on the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is called `iptables`.

The CentOS wiki has written a nice piece together about it: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables

Comment: @nikhil Indeed. Read, Learn, and Inwardly Digest NetFilter/IPTables. If you're admin'ing CentOS boxen, you need to understand how they're secured and this is an important part.